# debian stretch - libmysqlclient.a

Tags: debian, libmysql

I'm not a big fan of debian to begin with and this problem that I am facing at the moment makes me hate it.

I want a static version of the libmysqlclient on debian but it seems impossible to find.

I have installed everything with libmysql* and libmariadb* including the dev packages.

I only get the shared library.

Does anyone know how to solve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [searched for libmysqlclient](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libmysqlclient) as a filename across all packages and came up with [libmariadb-dev-compat](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libmariadb-dev-compat/filelist) that has a static version of libmysqlclient.

However I am having some difficulty getting it installed as it seems to conflict with some of the mariadb packages!